# Formatting data with linq into a new object

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have deserialized an this json object below and I would like to reformat it into the new object using linq in c# and i am wondering if anyone can please help me.

I deserialized the object into a class

```
public class Data
{
    public string title{get;set;};
    public List<Weight> Weight{get;set;}
}

public class Weight
{
    public DateTime Date{get;set;}
    public string weight{get;set;}
}
```

```
"title": "Paul weight log",
"weight": [
    {
        "date": "2017-04-21T00:00:00Z",
        "weight": "120kg", 
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-09-15T00:00:00Z",
        "weight": "125kg", 
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-10-27T00:00:00Z",
        "weight": "130kg", 
    },
]
}
```

This is format that i would like to have it in now.

```
"title": "Paul weight log" "date": "2017-04-21T00:00:00Z" "weight": "120kg"
"title": "Paul weight log" "date": "2017-04-21T00:00:00Z" "weight": "125kg"
"title": "Paul weight log" "date": "2017-10-27T00:00:00Z" "weight": "130kg"
```

What i tried doing is a Creating a new Class

```
public class Info
{
    public string title{get;set;}
    public string weight{get;set;}
    public DateTime Date{get;set;}
}
```

Then i tried using a foreach like on deserialized object.

```
des.Data.forEach(c =>
{
    new Info()
    {
        Title = c.Title,
        Date = c.date,
        Weight =c.weight 
    };
});
```

Comment: You forgot to post the code with which you are having trouble.

Comment: Sorry Stuart i thought that it would be too much code to but into the question and i am fairly stuck on it. I also tried using selectmany

Comment: Use `select()` extension of linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1) method to project every `Weight` instance to `Info`. Then assign the result to a separate variable (assuming that `data` is instance of `Data` class)

```cs
var result = data.Weight
    .Select(w => new Info { Date = w.Date, weight = w.weight, title = data.title })
    .ToList();
```

`Foreach` method in your code can't return anything

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with `SelectMany`, because you have to create a flattened list of `Data` multiplied by their `Weight`s:

```cs
from d in data
from w in d.Weight
select new
{
    d.title,
    w.Date,
    w.weight
}
```

Which is equal to `SelectMany` under the surface:

```cs
data.SelectMany(d => d.Weight, 
    (d, w) => new { d.title, w.Date, w.weight })
```

Here, `data` is an `IEnumerable<Data>`.

Answer (score 0):

Using your original class definitions, I put together a small, working ASP.NET Core console app (see code below).

The conversion from `Data` object to the `Info` object happens in the LINQ query that is the parameter to `infoList.AddRange(...);`.

`GetData()` is a local function that just builds an `IList<Data>` containing a couple of `Data` objects each with an embedded `IList<Weight>` collection. The result should be analogous to the contents of the `des` object in your code.

Note that `.SelectMany()` queries the `IList<Data>` returned by `GetData()` and returns an `IEnumerable<>` containing one or more objects for each object in the collection on which it is called. Note that `.Select()` and `.SelectMany()` differ in that `.Select()` produces only one output object for each object in the original collection while `.SelectMany()` can return multiple output objects for each input object.

The argument to `.SelectMany()` is a lambda, `d => d.Weight.Select(w => ...)`. This is important because the `Data` class contains a **collection** (i.e., `IList<Weight>`) of Weight objects. This allow us to have access the `Data` object in the `d` argument and each of the Weight objects -- one at a time -- in the `w` argument.

Lastly, `.Select(...)` returns a new `Info` object for each `Weight` object containing the property values as show in the code.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace LinqReformatObject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var infoList = new List<Info>();

            infoList.AddRange(
                GetData()
                    .SelectMany(d =>
                        d.Weight
                            .Select(w =>
                                new Info
                                {
                                    title = d.title,
                                    weight = w.weight,
                                    Date = w.Date
                                }
                            )
                    )
            );

            foreach (var i in infoList)
            {
                Console.Write($"\"title\": \"{i.title}\", ");
                Console.Write($"\"date\": \"{i.Date.ToString("O")}\",");
                Console.Write($"\"weight\": \"{i.weight}\"");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        }

    public class Data
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public List<Weight> Weight { get; set; }
    }

    public class Weight
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string weight { get; set; }
    }

    public class Info
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string weight { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }

        static IList<Data> GetData()
        {
            return new List<Data>()
            {
                new Data() {
                    title = "Paul's weight log",
                    Weight = new List<Weight>() {
                        new Weight () {
                            Date = DateTime.Parse("2017-04-21T00:00:00Z"),
                            weight = "120kg"
                        },
                        new Weight () {
                            Date = DateTime.Parse("2017-09-15T00:00:00Z"),
                            weight = "125kg"
                        },
                        new Weight () {
                            Date = DateTime.Parse("2017-10-27T00:00:00Z"),
                            weight = "130kg"
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Data() {
                    title = "John's weight log",
                    Weight = new List<Weight>() {
                        new Weight () {
                            Date = DateTime.Parse("2017-06-21T00:00:00Z"),
                            weight = "101kg"
                        },
                        new Weight () {
                            Date = DateTime.Parse("2017-08-15T00:00:00Z"),
                            weight = "98kg"
                        },
                        new Weight () {
                            Date = DateTime.Parse("2017-11-27T00:00:00Z"),
                            weight = "94kg"
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Data() {
                    title = "Ringo's weight log",
                    Weight = new List<Weight>() {
                        new Weight () {
                            Date = DateTime.Parse("2017-03-21T00:00:00Z"),
                            weight = "98kg"
                        },
                        new Weight () {
                            Date = DateTime.Parse("2017-06-15T00:00:00Z"),
                            weight = "100kg"
                        },
                        new Weight () {
                            Date = DateTime.Parse("2017-09-27T00:00:00Z"),
                            weight = "102kg"
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Data() {
                    title = "George's weight log",
                    Weight = new List<Weight>() {
                        new Weight () {
                            Date = DateTime.Parse("2017-01-21T00:00:00Z"),
                            weight = "99kg"
                        },
                        new Weight () {
                            Date = DateTime.Parse("2017-03-15T00:00:00Z"),
                            weight = "103kg"
                        },
                        new Weight () {
                            Date = DateTime.Parse("2017-05-17T00:00:00Z"),
                            weight = "113kg"
                        },
                        new Weight () {
                            Date = DateTime.Parse("2017-07-19T00:00:00Z"),
                            weight = "111kg"
                        },
                        new Weight () {
                            Date = DateTime.Parse("2017-09-23T00:00:00Z"),
                            weight = "109kg"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```